# How to read a list of fixed items and fill a dictionary in each position?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

In Python3, I have a list:

```
print(lines)
[<td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1455705">Inq 138</a></td>, <td>0000344-45.1983.0.01.0000</td>, <td>29/04/1983</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1458035">Inq 170</a></td>, <td>0000243-71.1984.0.01.0000</td>, <td>23/03/1984</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1460780">Inq 202</a></td>, <td>0000199-18.1985.0.01.0000</td>, <td>26/02/1985</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1463215">Inq 228</a></td>, <td>0001497-45.1985.0.01.0000</td>, <td>04/11/1985</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1463278">Inq 229</a></td>, <td>0001526-95.1985.0.01.0000</td>, <td>11/11/1985</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2547059">AP 449</a></td>, <td>0004490-89.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>14/08/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1471162">Inq 351</a></td>, <td>0001562-69.1987.0.01.0000</td>, <td>09/09/1987</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1740074">Inq 1430</a></td>, <td>0004092-60.1998.0.01.0000</td>, <td>04/12/1998</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1828698">Inq 1644</a></td>, <td>0002280-12.2000.0.01.0000</td>, <td>27/06/2000</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1654821">Inq 1249</a></td>, <td>0003249-66.1996.0.01.0000</td>, <td>18/11/1996</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1656655">Inq 1268</a></td>, <td>0003587-40.1996.0.01.0000</td>, <td>20/12/1996</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2507567">Inq 2518</a></td>, <td>0001854-53.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>16/04/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2095269">Inq 1901</a></td>, <td>0000494-25.2003.0.01.0000</td>, <td>12/02/2003</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2492743">Inq 2469</a></td>, <td>0000746-86.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>21/02/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2043710">Inq 1837</a></td>, <td>0002951-64.2002.0.01.0000</td>, <td>16/08/2002</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2257373">Rcl 2980</a></td>, <td>0004831-23.2004.0.01.0000</td>, <td>23/11/2004</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2257351">Rcl 2984</a></td>, <td>0004822-61.2004.0.01.0000</td>, <td>23/11/2004</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1878794">Pet 2188</a></td>, <td>0003954-25.2000.0.01.0000</td>, <td>14/11/2000</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2296897">Rcl 3338</a></td>, <td>0002065-60.2005.0.01.0000</td>, <td>18/05/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2502232">Pet 3923</a></td>, <td>0001447-47.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>23/03/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2496217">Pet 3891</a></td>, <td>0000957-25.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>05/03/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2511735">Pet 3960</a></td>, <td>0002077-06.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>26/04/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2646528">Pet 4466</a></td>, <td>0006782-13.2008.0.01.0000</td>, <td>07/11/2008</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2550348">Pet 4132</a></td>, <td>0004655-39.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>23/08/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2549919">Pet 4133</a></td>, <td>0004636-33.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>23/08/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2485622">Rcl 4899</a></td>, <td>0000244-50.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>18/01/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2549328">MS 26863</a></td>, <td>0004617-27.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>22/08/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1615787">HC 72731</a></td>, <td>0001236-31.1995.0.01.0000</td>, <td>18/05/1995</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1438260">RE 77205</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>02/08/1973</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2326349">HC 86828</a></td>, <td>0004531-27.2005.0.01.0000</td>, <td>29/09/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2324699">HC 86759</a></td>, <td>0004378-91.2005.0.01.0000</td>, <td>22/09/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2330454">HC 86964</a></td>, <td>0004857-84.2005.0.01.0000</td>, <td>18/10/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2330831">HC 86991</a></td>, <td>0004913-20.2005.0.01.0000</td>, <td>20/10/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1450385">RE 93293</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>23/09/1980</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2659893">HC 97511</a></td>, <td>0000296-75.2009.0.01.0000</td>, <td>19/01/2009</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1553416">AI 148897</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>27/11/1992</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1625874">AI 176743</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>02/10/1995</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1719177">AI 223221</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>09/07/1998</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1742963">RE 242546</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>21/12/1998</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1886488">AI 323305</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>01/12/2000</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2119361">AI 446706</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>02/05/2003</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2136833">AI 457100</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>24/06/2003</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2202205">AI 495324</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>13/02/2004</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2193004">AI 489263</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>07/01/2004</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2202682">AI 495714</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>17/02/2004</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2302168">AI 548966</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>07/06/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2500686">RE 540712</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>19/03/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2594212">RE 577771</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>13/02/2008</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2585030">RE 574636</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>31/12/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2328209">AI 564510</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>06/10/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2339607">AI 556727</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>30/11/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2327939">AI 564740</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>06/10/2005</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2577541">RE 571596</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>21/11/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2576950">RE 571366</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>19/11/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2575548">RE 570742</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>12/11/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2422042">AI 610979</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>04/10/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2425103">AI 613045</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>10/10/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2438074">AI 620055</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>06/11/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2429261">AI 613330</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>18/10/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2421798">AI 613011</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>04/10/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2428282">AI 614436</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>16/10/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2422311">AI 611851</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>04/10/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2416702">AI 607605</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>22/09/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2395268">AI 596356</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>28/07/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2456727">AI 631129</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>03/12/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2463210">AI 632771</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>10/12/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2533130">AI 668455</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>28/06/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2440814">AI 623286</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>10/11/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2442092">AI 623444</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>14/11/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2509817">AI 656365</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>23/04/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2476685">AI 634273</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>29/12/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2470012">AI 637744</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>17/12/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2463558">AI 635450</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>11/12/2006</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2568713">AI 688217</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>22/10/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2562790">AI 685015</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>02/10/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2569031">AI 688019</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>22/10/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2540446">AI 673117</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>20/07/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2500687">AI 651181</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>19/03/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2497975">AI 649978</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>09/03/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2626718">AI 720168</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>25/06/2008</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2626965">AI 720220</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>26/06/2008</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2613005">AI 712490</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>25/04/2008</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2544337">AI 675174</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>03/08/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2584538">AI 696448</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>19/12/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2571097">AI 689113</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>26/10/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2586710">AI 697555</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>07/01/2008</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2605248">AI 708183</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>25/03/2008</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2657612">AI 739587</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>28/12/2008</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2260296">AI 526303</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>07/12/2004</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2478066">RE 525709</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>03/01/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1456481">AR 1178</a></td>, <td>0000716-91.1983.0.01.0000</td>, <td>01/09/1983</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2549780">MS 26865</a></td>, <td>0004635-48.2007.0.01.0000</td>, <td>22/08/2007</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>, <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1553329">AI 130440</a></td>, <td> </td>, <td>26/11/1992</td>, <td>Físico</td>, <td>Público</td>]
```

It is a sequence of information from a table. Every 5 times it changes line. So to extract the first line I could do this:

```
a = "http://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/" + lines[0].a.get('href')
b = lines[1].string
c = lines[2].string
d = lines[3].string
e = lines[4].string
```

And in this case item 5 is the beginning of the second line: `a = "http://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/" + lines[5].a.get('href')`

I want to iterate in this list and add a dictionary, like this:

```
results = []
results.append({'column_a': "http://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/" + lines[0].a.get('href'), 
                                'column_b': lines[1].string, 
                                'column_c': lines[2].string, 
                                'column_d': lines[3].string, 
                                'column_e': lines[4].string)})
```

But a "for" in the list shows each item at a time

```
for item in lines:
        print (item)
```

Please, is there a way to go through the list in batches of five appearances at a time? Or another way to read this list and fill in the dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/953482)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cycle` from `itertools` can be useful her:

```
import itertools
import string

alph = string.ascii_lowercase


a = itertools.cycle(range(5))

for _ in range(40):
    index = a.next()
    mydict['column_{}'.format(alph[index])] = lines[index].string
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly this might give you idea:-

```
    d = {}
    for i in (range(5)):
        a = "http://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/" + lines[i].a.get('href')
        d[i] = a
    print(d)
```